# How scalable is Jetty?

Tags: java, c, jetty, libevent

Greetings! I wrote a highly scalable HTTP event (long-polling) server in C/C++ using libevent. However, it's messy, hardly portable, and lets face it: it's C. Let alone that I've been having some major issues with the mysqlcpp connector (which is complete trash), and some minor issues with libevent (it could be because I'm using 2.0.1-alpha). The event-server is C/C++, and the actual backend is PHP-fpm that I hit if I need to (i.e. if there's a new event). All the proxy/cgi routing is done through nginx.

I'm debating just re-writing the whole thing (event server and backend) in Java - I like using PHP for the front-end. I've heard many good things about Jetty, but I'm wondering if anyone's had experience deploying real-world highly-concurrent applications working on the Jetty backend. If so, how does it stack up when compared to an HTTP libevent implentation, or equivalent Erlang and Python server libraries?

**I'm not interested in `apachebench` benchmarks so please don't link them.** I'm interested in *concurrency* and *scalability*.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We've used Jetty's long-polling for a while and have been pretty happy with it. We've never been close to [10K+ concurrent users](http://cometdaily.com/2008/01/07/20000-reasons-that-comet-scales/) as was demonstrated by Jetty developers though. However, the added overhead of 300-400 concurrent Cometd connections was hardly noticeable on our low-end servers. Another article explains [clustering of Jetty and Cometd using Terracotta](https://webtide.com/clustering-cometd-with-terracotta/) (which is another awesome piece of software).